# How to switch custom xib cell when didSelect call?

Tags: swift, tableview, xib

I have a tableView with 2 custom xib cells. I want to switch the custom cell when user tapped it also adjust the cell height. How do I achieve it? I tried to use container view but then the height would be the same. I want to know if it is possible to do it with two xib for tableView cell? Thank you.

```
var isContactView: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ContactTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "contactCell")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DetailTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "detailCell")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //if ContactTableViewCell return 40
    //if DetailTableViewCell return 150
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //by default the cell view is ContactTableViewCell. 
    //When user tapped the cell it will change to DetailTableViewCell.
    if isContactView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell
        //do something...
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
        //do something...
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //not sure how to change the xib in here.
    
    //if cell view is ContactTableViewCell 
        cell view = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
        isContactView = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    
    //else 
        cell view = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell
        isContactView = true
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 cases:

1. If there's just single cell to be viewed, then just put the following code in didSelect:

isContactView = !isContactView

tableView.reloadData()

2. If there are multiple cells in which the condition is to be applied. Please put a key in your data model.

For example:

testArr is the array of objects that you are displaying in tableview. Then keep a key, say isContactView in this model. And put the login based upon this key.

Like in case of cellForRow:

```
if testArr[indexpath.row].isContactView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell
        //do something...
} else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
        //do something...
}
```

And in didselect:

```
isContactView = !testArr[indexPath.row].isContactView
```